# SOLVED : LDAP connection OK in CLI, fails in PHP-FPM

Tags: php, ldap

The very simple code below :

```
$ldap_server = "ldaps://myldap:636";
$ldap_user = "uid=bob,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=mydomain";
$ldap_passwd = "XXX";
$conn = ldap_connect($ldap_server);
ldap_bind ($conn, $ldap_user, $ldap_passwd);
echo (ldap_error ($conn));
```

echoes "Success" when called from the command line, but "Can't bind to server" when called from within a web page.
I've been all day long, googling many hours, on this problem. Read related threads here. No success...
And phpinfo() shows me the correct interpreter, not the php5.4 from base.

My environment :

> RedHat 7.9
>
> Apache 2.4 from base
>
> rh-php73 and friends from scl
>
> /etc/openldap/ldap.conf is empty

Thanks in advance for any help

[Edit] strace helped me, showing the the web user had no access to /etc/opendldap/cacerts

Comment: Have you tried setting the server IP instead of the hostname?

Comment: Ro, Thanks for the suggestion. However the probleme remains, I can connect in CLI :
`php foo.php` connects, while `http://server/foo.php` fails

Comment: My next guess it is a certificate issue. What does `ldap_set_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, 0);` give you?

Comment: Always set. In fact I tried with the following options :
`ldap_set_option ($conn, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 15);`
`ldap_set_option ($conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);`
`ldap_set_option ($conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);`
`ldap_set_option ($conn, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CRLCHECK, 0);`
`ldap_set_option ($conn, LDAP_OPT_DEREF, 3);`

Perhaps it is an environment variables problem ?

Comment: What makes you think that? It's unfortunate that something called `ldap_bind` only tells you it was 'unable to bind'. That is a terrible error message. Have you tried `ldap_get_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $err); var_dump($err);` yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried to retrieve the extender error,, but it is not supported by our LDAP.